# Not able to get all rows returned from Couchbase View using JAVA SDK

Tags: java, view, sdk, couchbase

ViewResult.allRows() is not returning all result from View, it is only returning a subset of result set.

ViewResult.totalRows() returns 70 but ViewResult.allRows().size() = 2 and below mentioned code itrates 2 time only

```
for (ViewRow row : viewResult) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Note: I am using java-client v 2.1.4

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what is the ViewQuery you executed? (including parameters)

Comment: Hi Simon, Now I am able to get all rows..
For this I have to publish my view to Production and add 'inclusive_end=true'. 
I was running my view in Development environment, due to which I was not getting Full Data Set.